# Live Server for Static Markdown Websites

Tags: web, static, markdown, vuepress

I am currently looking into static site generators.
I build a testing documentation site with Vuepress and am now fiddling with going into the live operation.
i don't want to publish my files to services (GitHub Pages, Netlify etc.) but I want to host it on my own server.
Generating static html sites everytime I add markdown pages or change the content is not an option.
Is there a way to host Vuepress (or maybe similar markdown generators) where I just need to upload the .md files and everything goes automatically?

Answer (score 0):

There are two basic ways to use markdown as your website...

**use a live server:**
In this scenario, each request is processed by a program which retrieves the markdown text and does some pre or post processing (templateengine, formatting etc).
This could be a simple CGI script, a web framework or a custom server.

**use a static site generator:**
You process the markdown on your lokal machine and generate static html files, which are uploaded and served by a web server.

To answer your question whether or how you can use vuepress:
There are multiple possible ways, depending on your current setup.
If you only have some webspace, than you have to upload prerendered html files (or using another framework).
If you have a virtual server, than you can automate the build/rending process by using scripts, e. g. with file watchers.

Note to GitHub:
Even if you said, that you don't want to use GH... If you only want to hide the markdown files, you can create a private repository and use GH Actions as CI/CD pipeline.

Unfortunately Stackoverflow is not for software recommendation, so for alternatives to vuepress have a lookt at [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: There is a third possibility and what I assume the OP is actually asking about: You could have a 'single page app' which loads in your browser. The Javascript within that page then retrieves static Markdown files from the server, runs them through a Markdown parser, and then inserts the rendered HTML into the page. I have seen a couple examples of this in recent years. However, they are certainly not the mainstream/typical way of doing things. I can't remember where I saw this and couldn't provide a recommendation if it was on-topic to do so.